# How do I search by tag on the Android Stack Exchange app?

Tags: support, android-app

Is there a way to search a Stack Exchange site by tag on the Android Stack Exchange app?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in the search box type the tag name between square brackets, followed by the search term:

> [image]

Comment: Isn't it interesting that you search for questions tagged `bug` and find one that isn't...a bug.

Comment: @Zondo: Hope he entered the `[bug] unicorn` in the search bar and not yet touch the Search option and took the screenshot. The questions in the screen filled with the `Relevant` activity. Its a coincident that those activity question also contain a `bug` tag, that causing the confusion.